# Azure offline sync local storage documentation

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement azure offline sync in my android application (on Java). I found [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data), but can't find any examples or documentation about using QueryOperations and Query.
I'll be appreciated for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the "How to: Query data from your Mobile App backend" section of the sibling page to the one you found, [Work with the Client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namequeryingahow-to-query-data-from-your-mobile-app-backend). The [Javadoc](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/) for the Mobile Apps Client SDK is also available, and of course there's also the [Java source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client).

Comment: I haven't found docs about MobileServiceSyncTable, but [tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/blob/master/e2etest/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/zumoe2etestapp/tests/OfflineTests.java) says more than docs